# How to disregard validation rules and messages in ajax when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

Below is my javascript code. As you have noticed, in my `$("#register-form").validate` the rules are all the same, which is `required:true` . since it's just that, I wanted to make it required in their input fields instead in the html. I did try it, therefore I deleted the entire code inside the comment `/* validation */` and added `required` in each of their input fields in my html form, but when I submit the form, it just reloads the page, not giving me the messages I was expecting in my `function submitForm()`. But if I use the entire code, it is submitting the form and gives me the correct alert message. So how will I disregard the rules and messages here? Since I already have `required` in my html input fields?

```
$('document').ready(function()
{
    /* validation */
     $("#register-form").validate({
      rules:
      {
            firstname: {
            required: true
            },
            lastname: {
            required: true
            },
            username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
            },
            password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 8
            },
            password2: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#password'
            },
            email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
            },
            answer: {
            required: true
            },
       },
       messages:
       {
            firstname:"Please input your firstname.",
            lastname:"Please input your lastname.",     
            answer:"Please input your answer.",
            username:{
                    required: "Please input your username.",
                    minlength: "Username must be atleast 8 characters"
                    },
            password:{
                      required: "Please input your password",
                      minlength: "Password must be atleast 8 characters"
                     },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
            password2:{
                        required: "Please re-type your password",
                        equalTo: "Password do not match!"
                      }
       },
       submitHandler: submitForm    
       });  
       /* validation */

       /* form submit */
       function submitForm()
       {        
                var data = $("#register-form").serialize();

                $.ajax({

                type : 'POST',
                url  : 'signup.php',
                data : data,
                beforeSend: function()
                {   
                    $("#error").fadeOut();
                    },
                success :  function(data)
                           {                        
                                if(data==2){

                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                                            alert('Email is already taken.');
                                            document.getElementById ("email").focus();

                                    });

                                }
                                else if(data==1){
                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){


                                            alert('Username is already taken.');
                                            document.getElementById ("username").focus();
                                    });
                                }
                                else if(data==3)
                                {

                                    alert('Registration successfully submitted.');
                                    window.location='index.php';

                                }
                                else{

                                    $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){

                                         $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+data+' !</div>');

                                    $("#btn-submit").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> &nbsp; Create Account');

                                    });

                                }
                           }
                });
                return false;
        }
       /* form submit */

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are using a plugin to validate your input and it calls the `submitHandler` function when tests pass. So if you want to get rid of that validation you need to bind your `submitForm` function to a submit event...

```
$('document')
  .ready(function () {

    /* form submit */
    function submitForm() {
      //do stuff and return false
      return false;
    }
    /* form submit */
    $("#register-form").on("submit",submitForm);    
  });
```